# Adding custom fields to images

Tags: custom-field, customization, post-meta

I want to show sources under my every images. So basicly I want to add a simple custom field. I added this code to my function.php

```
add_filter('attachment_fields_to_edit', 'edit_media_custom_field', 11, 2 );
add_filter('attachment_fields_to_save', 'save_media_custom_field', 11, 2 );
function edit_media_custom_field( $form_fields, $post ) {
    $form_fields['custom_field'] = array( 'label' => 'Custom Field', 'input' => 'text', 'value' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_custom_field', true ) );
    return $form_fields;
}
function save_media_custom_field( $post, $attachment ) {
    update_post_meta( $post['ID'], '_custom_field', $attachment['custom_field'] );
    return $post;
}
```

It is ok so far.But then things getting messy. Now my problem is where I can add this second calling code, I meant which .php

```
get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_custom_field', true ) );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you put it depends, you likely want to put the [`get_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) call:

```
echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_custom_field', true ) );
```

into the according [template file](http://codex.wordpress.org/Templates#Template_File_Articles). But of course you can also [hook into a filter or action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API) from your `functions.php` or a plugin.

Comment: I am sorry but I am not good with php coding. I just want to show this field under the images in single post page.

Comment: Just add it to your [single post template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Single_Post_display), you find that in the folder of the theme you are using. @user54672 Don't forget to tick the answer, if it helped you solving the problem.